# Google Feeds API not working - Has it been shutdown?

Tags: rss-reader, google-feed-api

I just opened up my news website that I'm working on this morning and none of the RSS news feeds are being displayed, I went onto the Google Feed Forum to see if there had been anything posted about it and the only thing I found was this.

https://developers.google.com/feed/forum?place=topic%2Fgoogle-ajax-search-api%2FxP6mKdRA6n4%2Fdiscussion

So far there is no official confirmation that it has been shutdown but only speculation that it has been. If it has been shutdown, does that mean that everyone who has been using Google Feeds API up to this point will have to find an alternative? Is there any way we can continue to use it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/feed/: _“This API is officially deprecated. See our deprecation policy in our [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/feed/terms) for details.”_

Comment: @CBroe it was working no problem for me the past couple of weeks, only stopped working this morning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading RSS feed with AJAX: alternatives to Google Feed API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049813/loading-rss-feed-with-ajax-alternatives-to-google-feed-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are several treads opened like [Real alternative for Google Feed API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016263/real-alternative-for-google-feed-api)

I've found http://rss2json.com/api.json?rss_url= and works ok. 
Doesn't generate the exactly same structure, so you will have to tweak it.

ps: sorry, but i dont have enough rep to post a comment

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: Since I used rss2json as the alternative, I've accepted your answer :)

Comment: glad it helped you. let's hope this will last along time :)

Comment: Agreed! It'd be awful if this service disappears as well!

Answer (score 4):

Use Yahoo's [YQL service](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/):

```
select * from xml where url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/rss'
```

It even accepts a `callback` query string

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fnews.ycombinator.com%2Frss'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=mycallback
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my answer will help you, but it worked for what I needed.

I have resorted to using Google Alerts and http://feed.mikle.com tool.

Create an alert on www.google.com/alerts, and where is says "Deliver to", under "show options", select "RSS feed". Then save the alert.

Click the RSS button for your newly created alert, copy the URL and paste it on feed.mikle.com. Use the tool to customise your widget however you want, then simply copy the code on the right, and paste it onto your webpage.