# Loading RSS feed with AJAX: alternatives to Google Feed API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, rss

I've been using the Google Feed API to load RSS feeds, but it looks like Google has shut down the API. For instance, when I try to load the New York Times RSS feed at `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&q=http%3A%2F%2Frss.nytimes.com%2Fservices%2Fxml%2Frss%2Fnyt%2FHomePage.xml`, I get this response:

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.", "responseStatus": 403}
```

Are there any viable alternatives?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use Yahoo's [YQL API](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/):

```
select * from xml where url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/rss'
```

You can request a JSONP feed by adding a `callback` parameter to the url

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fnews.ycombinator.com%2Frss'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=mycallback
```

Comment: I hate to ask but could you provide a fiddle for this to show how it works? I would really appreciate and am not sure how your solution works or what will be displayed and how the HTML will look on the page.

Comment: @Aaron Here's a basic example to get you going: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f79807bc6abb00024df

Comment: Awesome! This really helps!

Comment: awesome! What about Google Feed API for finding rss page (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find), anyone can help me with this. I can't find the way to handle it with YQL

Comment: @meaholik I think Google discontinued Feed Find API too.

Comment: This doesn't work, the YQL API is deprecated and deactivated.

Answer (score 3):

***Deprecated***

[*My*](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS) [plugin](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS), [**$.jQRSS**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS) uses [**`Google Feed`**](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) and seems to work just fine, given your exact RSS link:

```js
var rss = 'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml';
$.jQRSS(rss, { count: 8 }, function (feed, entries) {
 console.log([feed, entries]);
 $.each(entries, function(i) {
  if (this['content']) {
   var fieldset = $('<fieldset/>', { title: this.contentSnippet }).appendTo('body'),
    legend = $('<legend/>').appendTo(fieldset),
    $link = $('<a />', { href: this.link, html: this.title, target: '_blank' }).appendTo(legend),
    $date = $('<h5 />', { html: this.publishedDate }).appendTo(fieldset),
    $content = $('<div />', { html: this.content }).appendTo(fieldset);
   $content.find('br').remove();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
fieldset > h5 { float: right; margin-top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS/master/jQRSS.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's weird. It's working again for me too, but the API is still officially deprecated: https://developers.google.com/feed/

Comment: Please don't rollback objectively good edits. You do not own your posts, the community does, and we are all free to edit and improve them. If you are not comfortable with this, you cannot post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This doesn't work, the API is deprecated and deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script feedburner:

<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/feeduri?format=sigpro&nItems=10" type="text/javascript"></script>

All information:

https://support.google.com/feedburner/answer/78991?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

One addition to Tony's solution for using YQL - I needed to [change the callback value to JSON_CALLBACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is) to parse the response properly:

```
'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20\'' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '\'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the API is deprecated and deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to grab a copy of whatever RSS feed you wish to display, then use client side JavaScript to display the results. The main advantage is you're not subject to daily requests limits that way, which most free RSS API services have, or reliability issues.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxticker/index.shtml