# Google RSS and Ajax stopped working yesterday

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss

Until yesterday, this code was working. But today I´m having this ERROR:

**TypeError: xml.responseData is null**

**CODE:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(function(){



var object001 = new Object(); 

        url = 'https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&csid=09160b44f4732e03&output=rss';
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            var values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            console.log(values);


        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Anyone knows WHY? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049813/loading-rss-feed-with-ajax-alternatives-to-google-feed-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Feeds API was shut down yesterday. An alternative is [to use Superfeedr](http://blog.superfeedr.com/google-feeds-api-welcome/).