# All Picasa slideshow gadgets stopped working - Error: This API is no longer available

Tags: rss, slideshow, picasa, google-gadget

I was using Picasa slideshow for a couple of years on multiple webpages and now it stopped working with popup window

Error: This API is no longer available.
[image]

example of webpage where the gadget is used: 
http://www.b-mont.sk/

Link to the original Google gadget:
https://ab56117cb9163641ca621ac5d4df8b73601b2f7a.googledrive.com/host/0B4yfJJJSNrfubzJEUkxIYm1PcHM/picasa-slideshow-simple-nb.xml

I think Google deprecated some of the features gadget is using.

Please help me to fix this gadget

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is working again at the moment, but that slideshow uses the deprecated Google Feed API: https://developers.google.com/feed/terms?hl=en#deprecation-policy. So it might go away at any time again. Here are some alternatives: [Loading RSS feed with AJAX: alternatives to Google Feed API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049813/loading-rss-feed-with-ajax-alternatives-to-google-feed-api)