# Insert iframe with random feed URL

Tags: javascript, iframe, feed

i would like to create a dynamic iframe who will show a random URL from a
 specific Feed i was able to make it once it worked fo a while but stopped
 working and wasn't able to make it work back anymore.

Here is the code below :

```
 <script>
function GetContent(feedUrl) {
    var feedApiGetJSON = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=15&callback=?&q=';
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: feedApiGetJSON + feedUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'JsonpCallback'
    });
}

function JsonpCallback(data) {
    if (data.responseStatus == "200") {
        //alert(data.responseData.feed.title);

        var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.responseData.feed.entries.length + 1);

        jQuery("#iframe_url").attr("src", data.responseData.feed.entries[e].link);


    }

}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    GetContent("http://bit.ly/1SyQdL0");
});
```

```
<iframe id="iframe_url" src="" style="border: 0px;height: 800px;width: 600px"></iframe>
```

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/92amatLf/6/)

Thanks For Help

Comment: Is your site running over HTTP or HTTPS? As for the fiddle you provided, JSfiddle uses a HTTPS connection, you try to make a XHR connection through HTTP, which is considered unsafe, and therefore not executed.

Comment: I changed links from https to https but still not working

Comment: I noticed, but this way you at least provide correct information and you won't get 30 or so answers telling you to use HTTPS

Comment: ok Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

```
/* callback */JsonpCallback({"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.", "responseStatus": 403})
```

https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide

"This API is officially deprecated. See our deprecation policy in our Terms of Service for details."

Probably your issue.

Comment: So is it google ajax that is not working ? and how can i ceate somthing simillar without google ajax ?

Comment: You can use an alternative like http://blog.superfeedr.com/google-feed-api-alternative/ There should be enough of a sample there for you get to get started.

Comment: I tried superfeedr.com when u want to generate the token that u need for your script it ask you for money. Any other FREE solution please!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was free. Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016263/real-alternative-for-google-feed-api